# PHP Session Handlers and PHPSESSID generation/verification

Tags: php, session, authentication, cookies

I noticed a strange behavior in PHP. In `php.ini`, `session.hash_function` is set to `sha256` and PHP generates an appropriate `PHPSESSID`, however, it will also take **ANY** value supplied by the user even it's much shorter.

```
wget --header="Cookie: PHPSESSID=notrandom" "http://someserver.com/test.php"
```

For example, the above line will trigger the session handler and create a new session for `notrandom` as if it was a valid session.

My question is two-fold:

1. - is this normal/desired behavior?
2. - is there a way for the session handler read/write functions to signal to PHP that the provided session ID is invalid (i.e not a `sha256`) and the session could not be started?
   - alternatively, if a client-supplied session ID is invalid (or just not found) would it not make more sense for the server to generate its own value (`session_regenerate_id`?) rather than use the one provided by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions, by convention, are there for the convenience of the website's visitors.  The fact that one is generated automatically (for new sessions) using a complex algorithm only helps to prevent session attacks, but shouldn't be relied on for that.  In more meaningful web applications, authentication and authorization should be used to secure the requests and responses to and from the web server.

To answer your questions more specifically:

1. Yes, this is the normal/desired behavior.
2. See @0x90's response; then use `session_status()` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php)) to decide what to do next.
3. Once you've implemented the changes from #2, above, you will have dealt with the situation where requests with invalid sessions are received and either create a valid one, or respond with the appropriate response code (403 - forbidden).

Comment: Got it! session_status() is probably the way to go but I don't have PHP 5.4 yet (still on 5.3), so found a work around by using the custom Session Handler to read() and check if the submitted PHPSESSID is present. This is only done on pages which require an existing session - other will call session_start() and bypass this issue/solution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a security problem as it leads to Session Fixation. This class of vulnerability is quite common and equally commonly exploited.

You need to set `session.use_strict_mode=On` in your PHP.ini to prevent PHP from accepting these arbitrarily set session IDs.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.php